# Inject Symfony Service in a Bundle for Akeneo Pim

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I am trying to inject a service from Akeneo to my selfwritten Bundle.
To be exact, i want to use the service defined [here](https://docs.akeneo.com/5.0/manipulate_pim_data/non-product/query.html)  in my bundle instead of an Processor.

```
services:
     _defaults:
         autowire: true
         autoconfigure: true
     Acme\CategoryBuilder:
         class: Acme\CategoryBuilder\CategoryBuilder
         arguments:
             - '@pim_catalog.repository.category'
         tags:
             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: akeneo.storage.post_save, method: onPostSave }
```

and this constructor:

```
public function __construct(CategoryRepositoryInterface
$categoryRepositoryInterface){
         $this->categoryRepositoryInterface = $categoryRepositoryInterface;
}
```

in a Class called CategoryBuilder.
This setup does not work and if i try to clear & warmup the cache, i get the Error Response that 0 arguments are passed but 1 was expected.
How can i pass this service to my Bundle?

Edit:

if i run:  `php bin/console debug:container pim_catalog.repository.category` i get the following output:

```
Information for Service "pim_catalog.repository.category"
=========================================================

 Category repository

 ----------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Option            Value                                                                               
 ----------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Service ID        pim_catalog.repository.category                                                     
  Class             Akeneo\Tool\Bundle\ClassificationBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\CategoryRepository  
  Tags              pim_repository                                                                      
  Public            no                                                                                  
  Synthetic         no                                                                                  
  Lazy              no                                                                                  
  Shared            yes                                                                                 
  Abstract          no                                                                                  
  Autowired         no                                                                                  
  Autoconfigured    no                                                                                  
  Factory Service   doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager                                                 
  Factory Method    getRepository                                                                       
 ----------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


 ! [NOTE] The "pim_catalog.repository.category" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was     
 !        compiled.
```

Does the Note mean i just cant get this Service? If so, how can i restore it?

Comment: Your service id needs to be the fully qualified class name: `Acme\CategoryBuilder\CategoryBuilder` instead of just `Acme\CategoryBuilder`.  What is happening is that autowire is picking up the full class and trying to wire it.  BTW, it is recommended that you avoid autowire in bundles but it won't hurt.

Comment: i changed that but sadly same error. nothing changed.

Comment: I guess that the service has been removed because it's a private service. Could you change it into a public service and try again?

Comment: It is only being removed because it is not being injected.  Which means your CategoryBuilder service is not being defined.  There are all kinds of reasons why a bundle might not be properly setup to define services.  Do any of your bundle services work?  Might want to spend some time looking at how bundles are defined.

Comment: yes my bundle works. if i remove the expected service from the constructor and leave it empty, everything works as expected. My bundles communicates with an api and i want to speed it up by using a Doctrine Interface provided by akeneo, thats why i need the service.

Comment: it is said that none service gets injected. For testing i tried to pass arguments such as "@logger" which is definitly active and same failure happens there too